# Pick <li> from div1, on button click, move to div2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this is going to be an easy thing to do for someone with javascript experience, but I'm drawing a blank.

I have a list of items:

```
<div id="left-side">
    <ul>
        <li><div>Item 1</div></li>
        <li><div>Item 2</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<input id="addElement" type="button" value="->"/>

<div id="right-side">
</div>
```

I would like to highlight(change the background color) the selected list item on the left and then on a click of the button, move the selected item to the right div, and finally changing the background color back.

I've seen this many, many times online. But can't for the life of me, come up with how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight the selected list item on the left"?

Comment: are you using jQuery or pure javascript?

Comment: Have you looked at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/)? You may be interested in learning more about that very first function listed.

Comment: By highlight, I mean simply changing the background color so the user knows which li is selected.

Comment: @RômuloSpier either works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (jquery) should do the trick:

```
// make the items selectable by toogling an 'active' class
$('#left-side li').click(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('active');   
});

// on click of the move button
$('#addElement').click(function() {
    // get the items to move
    var $items =  $('#left-side li.active');
    // remove their active state
    $items.removeClass('active');
    // append them to the right side list
    $('#right-side ul').append($items);
});
```

As you can see the code is indeed pretty straigh forward.

I also set up a small example to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/NbcS9/

**edit:**
If you only want to be able to only select a single item on the left, you could do something like this in stead:

```
// make the items selectable by toogling an 'active' class
$('#left-side li').click(function () {
    // remove active class from all other items
    $('#left-side li').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
    // toggle the active class on the clicked item
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

And the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/NbcS9/1/

Comment: Its funny.. there are elements of all the answers provided here that make for one great solution.  (active vs selected) (remove active state)  (active = text color for subtle verification)  Nice work folks!

Comment: @PeterVR Nice! This is what I was thinking. What would need to change so you can only select one item at a time on the left?

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by adding an empty `<ul></ul>` to your right side div, then use this:

```
$('#left-side li').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
$('#addElement').click(function () {
    $('#left-side li.selected').appendTo($('#right-side ul'));
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wK6Mb/)**

Comment: +1.  It doesn't enforce a "single" selection, but elegant nonetheless.

Comment: @SeanBright - I didn't see that as a requirement, and selecting more than one at a time could be seen as a positive. However if that's the case, adding `$('#left-side li').not(this).removeClass('selected');` before `$(this).toggleClass('selected');` would remedy that. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wK6Mb/1/

Comment: It wasn't a requirement, but from a user experience standpoint I think that would be the expected behavior.  Although I do see the benefit of being able to select multiple.

Comment: @SeanBright I will need to do that, as the user can only select one item, some processing goes on, then it's added to the right. Thanks you for that tidbit.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$(function(){
    $('#left-side ul li').on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });

    $('#addElement').on('click', function(){
        $('#left-side ul li.selected').appendTo($('#right-side ul'));
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/9vFQD/)

Answer (score 0):

Using pure JavaScript would be tricky to do this, but using JQuery you can do this sort of easily. Add click events to the two divs which would append the selected text of the other to itself. to get the selected data add a function like this:

```
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
```

Also, I would look into Jquery Draggable(). sounds like something that could relate to your desired end result. http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: I have draggable now, but getting it to work with our Grails application is proving to be a P.I.T.A. So back to a button for now.

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
  .highlighted { background: yellow; }
```

html:

```
<div id="left-side">
    <ul>
        <li><div>Item 1</div></li>
        <li><div>Item 2</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<input id="addElement" type="button" value="->"/>

<div id="right-side">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#left-side').find('li').on('click', function(event) {

     $(this)
        .siblings().removeClass('highlighted')
        .end()
        .addClass('highlighted');

});


$('#addElement').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#left-side').find('li.highlighted').appendTo('#right-side ul'));
});
```